# Solving : $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y-z} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{z-x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{x-y}$ over $\mathbf{V} = (y-z,z-x,x-y)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I can't seem how to proceed with finding two curves $u_1$ and $u_2$ by solving the integral problem 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y-z} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{z-x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{x-y}$$
over the vector field $\mathbf{V} = (y-z,z-x,x-y)$. This is a part of proving that an integral surface is contained within $\mathbf{V}$. I would really appreciate any help given. Also Wolfram Alpha doesn't yield a solution for the problem : $$(y-z)u_x + (z-x)u_y + (x-y)u_z = 0$$

Comment: Hint: let $\phi = x + y +z$ and $\psi = x + y \omega + z\omega^2$ where $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}$. What is $d\phi$ and $d\psi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y-z} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{z-x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{x-y}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y-z} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y+dz}{z-y}$$
You deduce that 
$$x+y+z=C$$
You can use that to integrate another equation...

Edit

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y-z} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{z-x} $$
But you know that 
$$z=C-x-y$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{-C+x+2y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{C-2x-y} $$
$$({-C+x+2y})dy = dx({C-2x-y} )$$
note that $d(xy)=xdy+ydx$ so
$$({-C+2y})dy+dxy = ({C-2x} )dx$$
And note that $2xdx=dx^2$

$$-Cd(x+y)+dxy+dy^2 +dx^2=0$$

Thats easy to ntegrate....

Comment: Hi and thanks yet again for another answer. What do you mean by your last sentence ? Integrating what equation ?

Comment: you have z in function of x and y .....take two equalities with dx and dy and get rid of z

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks ! Was trying to grasp the meaning of the sentence. By the way, how come one gets familiar with such techniques starting from zero ?

Comment: I added some lines ...do them again and again till it becomes part of your brain

Comment: I understand the lines (thanks a lot). I am just asking about the tricks that you add the differential fractions for example and other stuff.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean...I did them again and again ...and practising also integration ...you learn also reading other people...